# Splash screen with glide issue as it is not working

Tags: android, android-glide, splash-screen

I am trying to make a splash screen which is using glide library  but
 even after trying many times i am unable to start the splash screen.
 Do i have to use Async task and how will i start an activity just
  after the splash screen. I have used

`com.master.android:glideimageview:1.0` and `com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.0.0-RC1` in my build.gradle(module)
 Please , guide me ?

Here is my code:

**splash.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent">

 <ImageView
    android:contentDescription="@string/splash_bg_cd"
    android:id="@+id/splash_bg"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/text_splash"
    android:textSize="@dimen/splash_text_size"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

and Java Code **Splash.java**

```
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.master.glideimageview.*;

public class Splash extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ImageView ivBgSplash;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState, @Nullable 
        PersistableBundle persistentState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);

        setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen);

        initViews();
     }

     private void initViews() {

        ivBgSplash = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.splash_bg);
        Glide.with(this)
                .load(R.drawable.hlb_logo)
                .into(ivBgSplash);
        AnimationDrawable splashAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) 
        ivBgSplash.getBackground();
        splashAnimation.start();
     }
}
```

Comment: Refer https://www.androidhive.info/2016/04/android-glide-image-library-building-image-gallery-app/

Comment: You might want to include the code where you are starting `SplashActivity`. It might be possible you are not even starting the `Activity`.

Comment: Is the activity not starting or are you unable to load the image?

Comment: Thanks coders, i have found that i will not user glide due to requirement , now will be using splash screen simple. It is working !!!

Answer (score 1):

Use this code

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            startActivity(new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));
        }
    }, 2000);
```